# TabBar in tablayout scrolls with the recyclerview below in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using tablayout and in the fragment there are recyclerviews... the problem is that the tabbar is scrolling with the recyclerview and i want the tablayout fixed(it should not scroll with the scrolling of the recyclerview), also it was working just fine with a listview in the fragment..

The below is my layout..(main_layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_toolbar"
        style="@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_content_main_tablayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabSelectedTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:tabTextColor="@color/white"
        app:tabBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_content_main_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

(recyclerview-layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

`app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in TabLayout tag.